# Bit-wise operations on addresses

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit, cpu-architecture

I have to solve a question saying

> The value of ab if ab & 0x3f equals 0x27.

For solving,I assumed let ab be `0xMN` and then  `N&f` means `N&1111` but here book says that `N&1111` should yield `0111` i.e. `7` =>N should be 7.
Similarly how `M&0011`should yield `2`the book says without telling how.

This maybe quite a simple to you people but i tried didn't succeed so here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it this way - a bit can only have 2 possible values i.e. 0 or 1. If you write down the binary  representations, you will end up with something like the below:

```
  abcd efgh
& 0011 1111
-----------
= 0010 0111
```

Going by the definition of `bitwise AND`, the values of a to h that would give the below result are 0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1 respectively. Converting back to hexadecimal, the value is 0x27.

As @jlahd points out in the comments below, three more values can satisfy this equation : 0x67, 0xa7 and 0xe7. This is because `x&0 = 0` so that `a` and `b` in the above could take any possible values without affecting the outcome.

Comment: The *only* possible values of `a` to `h`? What about `0x67`, `0xa7`, `0xe7`?

Comment: An additional point...Why are these represented as `0XMN` format i.e. `0X`?

Comment: 0x is used to distinguish hexadecimal and decimal representations e.g. 27 is a valid number in both systems, so 0x27 makes it clear that this is 27 in hex which has the decimal value 39.